# Example of bounded linear map $c\to \ell^\infty$ with $Ae_i=0$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am looking for an example of a non-zero bounded linear map $c\to \ell^\infty$ for which $Ae_i=0$ (the sequence $(e_i)_j=\delta_{ij}$).

The only thing I came up with so far is

$$(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)\mapsto (x_1 x_2,x_2x_3,x_3x_4,\ldots),$$
but this is not linear..

Comment: And what is $c$?

Comment: $c$ is usually the space of convergent sequences.

Comment: Yes, $c$ is the space of convergent sequences

Comment: I notice you deleted this question after getting an answer. That is unkind to your answerer and to others who encounter similar questions. It also makes it appear as though you're trying to hide something. Don't do that.

Comment: @davidlowryduda I thought it was a stupid question, however it is fine by me if it stays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x_i) \mapsto (\lim x_i) \cdot (1,1,1,1,1 ...)$